# problem with siunitx and multirow

Tags: siunitx, multirow

I am having trouble getting the `multirow` command to work with the `siunitx` package in the following example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llSSSS}
    \toprule
    A & B & {C} & {D} & {E} & {F} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Value 1} & \multirow{2}{*}{1.2e-4} & \multirow{2}{*}{1.0} & 3.0                  & \multirow{2}{*}{1.0} & 0.3 \\
                             &                         &                      & 4.0                  &                      & 0.7 \\ \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Value 2} & 3.2e-4                  & \multirow{2}{*}{2.0} & \multirow{2}{*}{1.0} & \multirow{2}{*}{9.2} & 0.4 \\
                             & 1.2e-8                  &                      &                      &                      & 0.5 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The only way I can remedy the error is to replace

```
\begin{tabular}{llSSSS}
```

with

```
\begin{tabular}{llcccc}
```

This, however, defeats the purpose of using the `siunitx` package in the present case.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Your example missed the `booktabs` package, and you also need to have braces around the non-numerical content in `S` columns, e.g. `{D}`. I took the liberty of fixing those things in your example, hope that's fine.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  If you add Thorbjørn's braces around the multirow commands `{\multirow{}...{}}` then you deal with the error, but might not get the expected alignment.

Comment: You are correct @AndrewSwann. This allows me to proceed without error and correctly formats values not within the multirow operator. I attempted to use the \tablenum command and received the error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]. ...\tablenum[table-format=1.2e-1]{1.2e-4}}} &`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A safer alternative is to use a `[c]` column and add `\tablenum` to all the numbers.  It isn't obvious from this example, but adding extra digits shows that it is working.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llcccS}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D & E & {F} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Value 1} & \multirow{2}*{1.2e-4} & \multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum{1.0}} & \tablenum{3.0}                  & \multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum{1.0}} & 0.3 \\
                             &                       &                                 & \tablenum{4.0}                  &                                 & 0.7 \\ \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Value 2} & 3.2e-4                & \multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum{2.0}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum{1.0}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\tablenum{9.2}} & 0.4 \\
                             & 1.2e-8                &                                 &                                 &                                 & 0.5 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without `multirow` and `siunitx` but `makecell` is added:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llcccc}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D & E & {F} \\
    \midrule
Value 1 & 1.2e-4    & 1.0   & \makecell{3.0\\ 4.0}      & 1.0   & \makecell{0.3\\ 0.7}  \\
    \midrule
Value 2 & \makecell{3.2e-4\\ 1.2e-8}    & 2.0   & 1.0   & 9.2   & \makecell{0.4\\0.5}   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]