# siunitx incompatible with multirow?

Tags: tables, siunitx, multirow, incompatibility

I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing the errors in this table. As written, I get about a dozen warnings (all on the first data line of the table) about missing `}` or `$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,size=footnotesize}
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c
            S[table-format=2.0] 
            *3{S[table-format=1.1]}
        }
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Homegrid}} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Battery capacity}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Load priority and power}} \\ \cmidrule{3-5}
        &       & \textbf{High} & \textbf{Medium} & \textbf{Low} \\ \midrule
        \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .447,  .741}{1} & 7     & 1.5   & 4.5   & 0 \\
        \textcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .325,  .098}{2} & 55    & 1.5   & 4.5   & 1.5 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Thresholds and actions for the homegrids of the experiment plotted in ...}
    \label{tab:export}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As soon as I switch the tabular format to `{ccccc}`, everything works perfectly.

I can use `\tablenum{}` (as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356851/106655)) in the middle column to get 7 and 55 to line up properly, which is why I'm using `siunitx`. But why won't siunitx work on it's own?

Comment: on my system this code compiles without warnings (`pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15`, `array 2014/10/28 v2.4c`, `siunitx 2014/10/01 v2.6c`)

Comment: @jakun I have more recent versions of all three (`pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17`, `array 2016/10/06 v2.4d`, and `siunitx 2017/03/23 v2.7f`) using `MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit` with TeXstudio.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `siunitx` code does it's best to 'guess' when content is 'purely textual', but it is best to give it some guidance. Here, the issue arises as `siunitx` picks up `\multirow` as 'before the number' but fails to grab all of the arguments in the same way. Adding a set of braces fixes this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,size=footnotesize}
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c
            S[table-format=2.0] 
            *3{S[table-format=1.1]}
        }
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Homegrid}} & 
        {\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Battery capacity}}} & % Braces here
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Load priority and power}} \\ \cmidrule{3-5}
        &       & {\textbf{High}} & {\textbf{Medium}} & {\textbf{Low}} \\ \midrule
        \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .447,  .741}{1} & 7     & 1.5   & 4.5   & 0 \\
        \textcolor[rgb]{ .851,  .325,  .098}{2} & 55    & 1.5   & 4.5   & 1.5 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Thresholds and actions for the homegrids of the experiment plotted in ...}
    \label{tab:export}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```