# I can't use \multirow at 'Temperature', 'Time', 'NaOH' and 'EtOH'

Tags: multirow

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{diagbox}%Make diagonal lines in tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Taguchi DOE with Factors and obtained response for \ce{NaOH} and \ce{EtOH} solvent systems.}
    \label{Table3pD}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|S[table-format=2.0(0)]|S[table-format=3.0(0)]|S[table-format=3.0(0)]|S[table-format=3.0(0)]|S[table-format=2.2]|S[table-format=2.2]|}
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{1.8cm}{\centering \textbf{Exp. Number}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Factors}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{2.8cm}{\centering \textbf{Polyphenols Components}}} \\
        & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
        \cline{2-7}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Solvent Concentration}} & {\textbf{Temperature}} & {\textbf{Time}} & {\textbf{\ce{NaOH}}} & {\textbf{\ce{EtOH}}} \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%I can't use \multirow at 'Temperature', 'Time', 'NaOH' and 'EtOH'
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Solvent Concentration}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Temperature}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Time}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\ce{NaOH}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\ce{EtOH}}} \\
        \cline{2-3}
        & \textbf{\ce{NaOH}} & \textbf{\ce{EtOH}} &  &  &  &  \\
        \cline{2-7}
        & \textbf{g/L} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{\celsius{}} & \textbf{min} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{\%} \\
        \hline
        1  & 3  & 0   & 40  & 20  & 8.31  & 8.36  \\
        2  & 3  & 0   & 55  & 40  & 9.38  & 10.94 \\
        3  & 3  & 0   & 70  & 60  & 13.27 & 14.59 \\
        4  & 3  & 0   & 85  & 80  & 20.22 & 19.56 \\
        5  & 3  & 0   & 100 & 100 & 17.13 & 17.36 \\
        6  & 6  & 25  & 40  & 40  & 14.14 & 13.87 \\
        7  & 6  & 25  & 55  & 60  & 15.75 & 16.99 \\
        8  & 6  & 25  & 70  & 80  & 18.02 & 17.52 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You could make your example a little more minimal by reducing the content of the table to the header and first line. Comment in the line that gives the error, and comment out the other one for convenience.

Comment: Try wrapping in curly brackets, for example `{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Temperature}}}`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: A `\multirow` cell needs special carae inside a column of type `S`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368679/47927

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes. Thank you.